# On click of asp.net button the page is coming to its page_load state

Tags: jquery, asp.net

On click of the asp.net Button, the page is coming to its original state as the page_load.I'm writing the click functionality of the button inside the jQuery's  $('document').ready() event.Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: When you say it's original state what do you mean?  ControlState?  I'd strongly suggest you post your code and talk us through it.  My gut from what you've said is that you're editing something in jQuery, the page is posting back and you're losing the changes you've made after the page has reloaded... however I can't answer without more information.  Your question is very unclear.

Comment: yep sorry for the inconvenience ....yep you are right about the losing the changes i have made after the page has reloaded

Comment: when the page posts back your page is rebuilt and any changes you made server side are lost.  Can you make your changes on a client side button or prevent the postback?  We may be able to suggest more if you edit your question and post code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the usual behaviour.

What you should do is, to keep your page initialization code (loading dropdown data etc..) in an if condition which checks whether this is a post back or not, in your Page_Load event. You may use the `IsPostBack` property of `Page` to check this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
     //code to load initial data (dropdown etc..)
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually the button i was taking is asp.net button instead i used HTML button and my problem is solved.But one more question if i have asp.net image button then how i'll solve it?because i'm not getting any answer for the imagebutton even if i'm using the IsPostBack property.

Comment: @akky: Use the postback property to determine whether it is a page postback or not. Please post the relevant details (including relevant code) as a new question.